# The problem with createAsyncThunk.withTypes: Cannot access 'createAsyncThunk' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I declared `createAsyncThunk.withTypes` in the file `store.ts`

```js
import { configureStore, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    home
})

export type ThunkApiConfig = {
  state: RootState
  dispatch: AppDispatch
}

export const createAppAsyncThunk =createAsyncThunk.withTypes<ThunkApiConfig>()

export default store
```

But when I used it in my slice

```js
import { createAppAsyncThunk } from '../../store'

interface State {
  selectedDate: string
}

const initialState = {
  selectedDate: '',
} as State

export const getCurrentUserPlace =createAppAsyncThunk(
  `${name}/getCurrentUserPlace`,
  (arg, thunkAPI) => {
    const sendDay = thunkAPI.getState().reservationPlaces.selectedDate
    return api.getCurrentUserPlace(arg, sendDay)
  },
)

const slice = createSlice({
  name,
  initialState,
  reducers: { },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(getCurrentUserPlace.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.currentUserReservation = action.payload
    })
  },
})

export default slice.reducer
```

I have an error:

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'createAppAsyncThunk' before initialization
>     at Module.createAppAsyncThunk (sp.ts:3:1)
>     at ./src/pages/ReservationPlaces/slice.ts (slice.ts:50:1)
> ```

I suppose, the problem of cross imports, but I don't know where I should write `createAsyncThunk.withTypes`.

I try to change import, but everything what I did - doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by moving `createAppAsyncThunk` into its own file and importing it from there instead.

Otherwise the parser hasn't had the time to reach that line before it parses your thunk files.

Hope it helps.